# Can Ubuntu remote access behind CGNAT?

Tags: networking, remote-access

**Remote access/desktop sharing/viewing** on the home network used to work with Ubuntu's [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) and [Remmina](https://remmina.org/) on a remote laptop, using port forwarding and an ISP with no CGNAT.

However the new [ISP's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) stops remote desktop sharing working.
From reading and research, a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or [tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) might be needed?

Is there an easy setup using remote access with Ubuntu?
I tried [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) but it needs a public WAN IP.

I've started looking at [TailScale](https://tailscale.com/) which is wrapped around [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/), but it's all new to me.

Just a simple home network solution would be good if a free VPS or something is needed?

Comment: You must have "something" accessible outside of your home network if you are behind a CGNAT, and some kind of tunnel set up between your home network and that "something". That "something" may be a VPS or some commercial remote access service - there are commercial services providing this feature (but they tend to be mostly Windows-only, like eg. GoToMyPC).

Comment: TeamViewer may be a solution. See also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Features  **NAT passthrough** column.

Comment: TeamViewer and AnyDesk are buggy and are a middleman. I'd prefer direct from my remote device to local device. I'm trying TailScale for now, however whilst I've connected, it's not clear how to view and control the GUI? OpenVPN failed as it needs a public WAN IP to issue a certificate. Might try WireGuard if I can't solve TailScale's remote viewing and control.

Comment: Test running command: $ sudo apt install netcat-openbsd && nc -vv 1.1.1.1 80
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
netcat-openbsd is already the newest version (1.218-4ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
Connection to 1.1.1.1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
Desktop viewing not working with Ubuntu's VNC and phone's RealVNC nor Laptop's Remmina. Still confused as TailScale tunnel is connected. Possibly port forward 5900?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using rdp, vnc is problematic with gnome.